# MS Project macro to send current .mpp with fixed recipients, subject and body

Tags: vba, email, outlook, attachment, ms-project

I am looking for a macro to send the .mpp where it is stored to a fixed recipients, subject and body

If i record a macro i have to include recipients, subject and body every time over and over, so it does not work

I wrote some code but i am unable to attach the current .mpp
.Could someone help?

```
Sub CreateMail()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
        .To = "aa@email.com"
        '.CC = "bb@email.com"
        .Subject = "Hi there"
        .Body = "Test"
        
OutMail.Display

End With

End Sub`
```

Answer (score 1):

If the current project has been saved then

```vb
Sub CreateMail()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .Attachments.Add (ActiveProject.FullName)
    .Display
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great!! I added the to, cc and subject to your code and it worked perfect! One more question if i may, how could I add the file name to the email subject? I would also need to add the word "update"

    .Subject = "FILE NAME HERE" & "update"

Comment: .Subject = ActiveProject.Name & "update"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.name